# How to enter an author name that has a surname and a Junior component but no first name?

Tags: bibliographies

In BibTeX and biblatex, it is well known that an author's name can have up to four components -- the firstname, von, surname, and Jr components. (The von component will turn out to be irrelevant for my purposes.)

If a certain author's name has FirstName, SurName, and Jr components, one can enter it easily as

```
author = "SurName, Jr, FirstName",
```

However, some names -- e.g., "Pliny the Younger", "Cato the Elder" -- have a surname and a Jr component but *but no FirstName component*. *Question: How does one enter such a name in a BibTeX database?*

The natural attempt,

```
author = "SurName, Jr.Component",
```

is not correct because BibTeX interprets `Jr.component` as `FirstName`. This matters because some bibliography styles abbreviate first names, whereas the Jr component is -- to the best of my knowledge -- never abbreviated. Moreover, some bibliography styles place the firstname component ahead of the surname component; that's never done -- again, to the best of my knowledge -- to the Jr. component. I've also found that

```
author = "SurName, Jr.Component, ",
```

i.e., attempting to provide an "empty" FirstName Component, doesn't work either as it throws a BibTeX error.

I should add that it's important that the surname and Jr.Component parts be recognized *separately* by BibTeX. Thus, `author = "{Pliny the Younger}"`, which treats the name as a single entity (a surname, actually), won't work for me.

---

*Addendum*: The use case that gave rise to this query is fairly unusual. I posted the query while trying to help the editor of an anthology of oral stories told by Amazon rainforest dwellers. Specifically, the task was to help organize and format the references and citation call-outs.

The story contributors all have only a single name each (no first names); some of the contributors are narrators, others are translators, etc. The book editor was looking to list the authors in the form

```
"XYZ, narrator and ABC, translator [remainder of formatted reference]"
```

in the references, and have citation call-outs of the form "XYZ and ABC". Note that the "narrator" and "translator" particles should show up only in the references (and should be separated from the names with a comma), but *not* in the citation call-outs.

My initial idea was to use the Jr component of a four-part bibtex-formated name to hold the authors' functional information (narrator, translator, etc): The Jr component is always typeset after the name, it is never abbreviated (the editor was using a bibliography style that abbreviates first names while listing them ahead of the surnames), and it is is separated from the (sur)name with a comma. Unfortunately, this idea didn't work, because the story tellers have single names, i.e., no separate first-name and last-name components...

In the end, I came up with a different solution: The `natbib` package allows setting up citation aliases. Thus, the `author` field could be defined as

```
author = "{XYZ, narrator} and {ABC, translator}",
```

and the citation call-out could be set to come out as "XYZ and ABC".  Whew!

Comment: `author={{Cato the Elder}}`

Comment: @egreg - I should have mentioned that I need to keep the surname and Jr components separate. For instance, the citation callout (in an authoryear citation system) should use just the surname component, i.e., say "Cato" -- not "Cato the Elder".

Comment: @egreg: I'd love to read ‘Epistolae, by Pliny, Jr’ — sure a best-seller;)

Comment: The usual question: do you own an original version of the “De senectute” by Cato Maior, whose name actually was “Marcus Porcius Cato”?

Comment: @egreg - I admit freely that I do *not* own an original copy of Cato Maior's famous treatise. (Do you?) For what it's worth, I do remember -- from long-ago high school days! -- the construction of some of the famous names of Classical Rome, say, Publius Cornelius Scipio Africanus Maior. However, my posting is really about *modern names* that contain only a surname component and a jr component -- and, specifically, how to enter them in the BibTeX `author` field. My apologies if mentioning "Cato the Elder" and "Pliny the Younger" as potential examples of such names misled you about my objective.

Comment: I don't think that the bibtex parser and the btparse library of biber has some "official" way to handle this case. Depending on system and the style you will have to add some dummy. (But `\relax` will not work with biber as the `\` will end as initial.) But you could make a feature request for biber for an "ignore me" input.

Comment: As indicate by @egreg, you can force the result with bracket.

Comment: With `biblatex` and its extended name format (only supported by Biber) you can give name parts explicitly. But then you could also not abuse the junior part, but define a dedicated part for your needs here (see the second part of my answer to [CJK Bibliography Problem, Biblatex-Chicago](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320738/35864)).

Comment: @moewe (and others) - I'm offering a bounty for a biblatex-based answer. :-)

Comment: For the use case described in the addendum, BibLaTeX also offers the option of using the "translator" field, rather than listing both narrators and translators in the author list. Other roles can also be defined using the editora, editorb, editorc fields. Whether the resulting format would match the publisher's expectations I cannot say.

Comment: @MarcSchulder - Thanks. That's what's proposed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325207/5001) as well, right?

Comment: @Mico - [The answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325207/5001) suggests listing everyone in the _authors_ field and adding a _role_ component to the name. This reproduces your addendum output example most faithfully. My suggestion is to use different list fields instead, e.g. `author={XYZ and ZYX}, translator={ABC and CBA}},`. The resulting bibliography would list all authors first and then later the translators (similar to editors). This is slightly different from your output example, but requires no custom macros. I can write it up as a full answer if you're interested.

Comment: @MarcSchulder - Yes, please go ahead and post an answer in which you elaborate these ideas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
@book{Surname:2015,
  author={Name {Surname Jr.}},
  title={Book Title},
  publisher={Publisher},
  year={2015}
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to post an answer. Unfortunately, the use case that gave rise to the query is quite unusual and isn't addressed by your proposed method. I've posted an addendum to my posting, in which I explain the use case in more detail as well as how I ended up solving the problem.

Comment: I'm reading now. Yours it is a good idea.

Answer (score 13):

With the upcoming `biblatex` 3.5/Biber 2.6 Biber supports an extended format to give names. You can specify the nameparts separately and don't have to rely on BibTeX's name parsing. There you could just use

```
author = {family=XYZ, suffix=translator},
```

This format can be combined with the standard input form

```
author = {family=XYZ, suffix=translator and James Miller},
```

---

But you could make use of the extended name format to an even higher degree. (See also [Bibliography according to icelandic system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287732/35864), [Use only the last name as namepartfamily instead of everything after prefix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308625/35864) and [Bibtex/Biber: how to cite an author using Ethiopian conventions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313176/35864))

Here I follow my approach from [CJK Bibliography Problem, Biblatex-Chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320693/35864)

We can introduce a new namepart `role` with the `.dbx`

```
\ProvidesFile{mico.dbx}[2016/08/17 extended name format for biblatex]
\DeclareDatamodelConstant[type=list]{nameparts}{prefix,family,suffix,given,role}
```

Then we just need a new macro to print the name with role, say

```
\newbibmacro*{name:role}[3]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\addcomma\space\mkbibnamerole{#3}}}
```

Then we need to make our name format choose this macro if the `role` is present

```
\DeclareNameFormat{given-family}{%
  \ifdefvoid{\namepartrole}
    {\ifgiveninits
        {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiveni}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiven}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:role}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartrole}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mico.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{mico.dbx}[2016/08/17 extended name format for biblatex]
\DeclareDatamodelConstant[type=list]{nameparts}{prefix,family,suffix,given,role}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{xyz,
  title  = {A Story},
  author = {family=XYZ, role=translator and family=ABC, role=narrator},
  year   = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, datamodel=mico]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{name:role}[3]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\addcomma\space\mkbibnamerole{#3}}}

\DeclareNameFormat{given-family}{%
  \ifdefvoid{\namepartrole}
    {\ifgiveninits
        {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiveni}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiven}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:role}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartrole}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}

\begin{document}
  \cite{xyz}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives in citations

> XYZ and ABC 2011

and in the references

> XYZ, translator and ABC, narrator (2011). *A Story.*

Comment: Many thanks for posting a biblatex-based answer! I find it very instructive.

Comment: Great answer! I was unaware of this new capabilities of Biber and the latest biblatex manual did not help much (or I glanced through it too quickly...). Many thanks