# Bibliography according to icelandic system

Tags: biblatex

The icelandic bibliography system requires sorting authors by *surname comma first name* (if not icelanders) and by first name **no comma** patronymic (if icelanders).

I'm using biblatex-chicago and polyglossia. While sorting by surname is set by default, I can't find any solution to sort the icelandic authors by their first name nor to skip the comma in between.

Comment: Have you considered treating the Icelanders as "corporate authors", by encasing their names in pairs of curly braces? That way, `"{Arnar Vigfusson}"` and `"{Sigridur Benediktsdottir}"` would get sorted under "A" and "S", respectively.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: The upcoming version of `biblatex` will be able to deal with Icelandic customs a bit better, see for example [this git commit](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/830cdc018411ac37a5702ffbf3e0c38208361de0). I'm not sure though, if this feature can be enabled on a per-entry basis.

Comment: I'm looking into this for biblatex/biber as part of general name handling enhancements. I'm assuming it would need to be set per-entry at least. To really do this properly, the bibtex data format just isn't suitable as you need as way of coding that a namepart is a patronymic etc. That's the purpose of the experimental biblatexml format.

Comment: @PLK Yes but ... Is this really a _good_format to output: as a reader it sounds like a nightmare!

Comment: That's true - the ability to mix name sorting keys per-name sounds to me like a recipe for confusion but I can imagine there are times when it makes sense in a data model where there are more name parts that the vanilla Western last/first arrangement.

Comment: You only mention the sorting, but this should also apply to how citations look, right? (Since a reader should be able to look up a citation in the bibliography. So do you then want full names in citations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could treat the names of Icelanders as "corporate authors", by encasing their names in pairs of curly braces. That way `"{Arnar Vigfusson}"` and `"{Sigridur Benediktsdottir}"` -- `{{Arnar Vigfusson}}` and `{{Sigridur Benediktsdottir}}`would work too, of course -- will get sorted under "A" and "S", respectively, rather than under "V" and "B". Moreover, no comma will be inserted between the given name and the patronymic.

Comment: Although this works, it seems like a bit of a hack, since the same `.bib` file can't be used for more standard styles.  So a long term solution would require changing the order based on an extra `.bib` file field rather than changing the names in the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 6):

Using biblatex 3.3 and biber 2.4 (currently in development folders on Sourceforge), you can customise the sorting keys used to sort names and you can do this at various scopes. One way of tackling your problem is:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{test1,
  OPTIONS = {sortnamekeyscheme=givenfirst},
  AUTHOR = {Arnar Vigfusson},
  TITLE  = {One},
  DATE   = {1983}
}

@BOOK{test2,
  OPTIONS = {sortnamekeyscheme=givenfirst},
  AUTHOR = {Sigridur Benediktsdottir},
  TITLE  = {Two},
  DATE   = {1983}
}

@BOOK{test3,
  AUTHOR = {Brian Yellow},
  TITLE  = {Three},
  DATE   = {1983}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSortingNamekeyScheme[givenfirst]{
  \keypart{
    \namepart{given}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{family}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\textcite{test1,test2,test3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here you can see that the new command `\DeclareSortingNameScheme` is used to define a new named scheme for constructing name sorting keys. This can be referred to at several scopes - globally (default), as part of a reference context, as a per-entry option (as in this example) or, with BibLaTeXML data sources, you can even do this at per name-list or per-name scope so that you can mix Icelandic and non-Icelandic names in the same entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bltxml}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="test7.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<!-- Auto-generated by Biber::Output::biblatexml -->

<bltx:entries xmlns:bltx="http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/biblatexml">
  <bltx:entry id="test1" entrytype="book">
    <bltx:names type="author">
      <bltx:name sortnamekeyscheme="givenfirst">
        <bltx:namepart type="family" initial="V">Vigfusson</bltx:namepart>
        <bltx:namepart type="given" initial="A">Arnar</bltx:namepart>
      </bltx:name>
    </bltx:names>
    <bltx:title>One</bltx:title>
    <bltx:date>1983</bltx:date>
  </bltx:entry>
  <bltx:entry id="test2" entrytype="book">
    <bltx:names type="author" sortnamekeyscheme="givenfirst">
      <bltx:name>
        <bltx:namepart type="family" initial="B">Benediktsdottir</bltx:namepart>
        <bltx:namepart type="given" initial="S">Sigridur</bltx:namepart>
      </bltx:name>
    </bltx:names>
    <bltx:title>Two</bltx:title>
    <bltx:date>1983</bltx:date>
  </bltx:entry>
  <bltx:entry id="test3" entrytype="book">
    <bltx:names type="author">
      <bltx:name>
        <bltx:namepart type="family" initial="Y">Yellow</bltx:namepart>
        <bltx:namepart type="given" initial="B">Brian</bltx:namepart>
      </bltx:name>
    </bltx:names>
    <bltx:title>Three</bltx:title>
    <bltx:date>1983</bltx:date>
  </bltx:entry>
</bltx:entries>
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[datatype=biblatexml]{\jobname.bltxml}

\DeclareSortingNamekeyScheme[givenfirst]{
  \keypart{
    \namepart{given}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{family}
  }
}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \ifsortnamekeyscheme{givenfirst}
    {\ifgiveninits
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{document}
\textcite{test1,test2,test3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a new test `\ifsortnamekeyscheme` which you can use to detect which scheme was used for a particular name. You can insert literals (like spaces, commas) into the name key scheme and also have compound name parts etc. I am looking into implementing more generic name handling for things like patronymics etc.

The name parts system in biblatex 3.3/biber 2.4 has been significantly changed and it is now possible, using a modern datasource like biblatexml, to define and use arbitrary name parts like "patronymic" etc. See the DEV branch biblatex PDF documentation for a complete example.