# Remove abbreviation dot for one letter word in biblatex's name disambiguation

Tags: biblatex, biber

Biblatex's disambiguation of names uses, by default, the abbreviation of other name parts when a labelname becomes ambiguous. But, unfortunately it adds the abbreviation dot even in one letter words. For example, in Portuguese one can find names with the preposition "e" (stands for "and" in English). And biblatex inappropriately "abbreviates" it as "e."

How can I remove the abbreviation dot in this case?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Silva2000,
    author = {Silva, Edmundo de Macedo Soares e},
    title = {Title},
    date = {2000},
}

@book{Silva2010,
    author = {Silva, Ligia Osorio},
    title = {Title 2},
    date = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcites{Silva2000}{Silva2010}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is - if I understand correctly - that `de Macedo Soares e` is not really a first name (that's where it is currently) and not really the 'primary' last name either. So to get this right one might have to define new name parts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313176/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288041/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320693/35864

Comment: Of course you could also ask PLK to stop biber inserting `\bibinitperiod` after lower-case one-letter name bits, but I'm not sure that is possible/desirable. All of this already happens in the Biber stages, `biblatex` can't really do anything about this.

Comment: BTW: How do I know where to 'make the cut' with names like this? Why is 'Artur da Costa e Silva' always 'Costa e Silva'. And why does Wikipedia call 'Edmundo de Macedo Soares e Silva' 'Macedo Soares' when you seem to want 'Silva'?

Comment: @moewe, that would definitely be overkill. Names in Portuguese are generally in the western tradition. Of course, I could as well say his family name is "Macedo Soares e Silva". But I'd say it is common to have these "middle family names", not only in for Portuguese names.

Comment: As to your last question the advice that I usually find to this respect is to render the name as it is commonly done by others or by the author him/herself. "Costa e Silva" is usually called so. And it gets worse: this particular "Edmundo de Macedo Soares e Silva" is very commonly referred to as "Macedo Soares".

Comment: @moewe, I also think that, if this is done within biber, I'll live with it for the moment. I'll try to exert some more control in the entry specifying the nameparts, without defining new ones. I can specify directly `giveni` and `familyi` can't I?

Comment: Yes you can (`giveni` is called `given-i` in the extended `.bib` format and `family`/`family-i` is never used), but the problem is that Biber still adds `\bibinitperiod` in `given-i`/`giveni` even if you put none there. You could hack something together using `prefix`, but that will of course cause problems for 'van Beethoven' and friends.

Comment: @moewe, Indeed I recall something in this direction in a question about adding "Prof.-Dr." or so. That doesn't leave me with much choice. But I actually think I can kill two birds with one stone, for I do find it somewhat strange to add short particle names for disambiguation, as the "de" (=von) and the "e", so perhaps I can go with `given-i=E. M. S.`.

Comment: @moewe Still, thank you very much for your input. Btw, do you think this question is worth keeping? I'd be inclined to delete it, I think.

Comment: It might help others if you can write down what you eventually went with. If you don't want to write such an answer there is probably not much value in the question being kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I just found out how to do this for [Use only the last name as namepartfamily instead of everything after prefix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308625/35864) I'll add an answer here as well. You can use `{de\nopunct}` and `{e\nopunct}` in the `given-i` name part to suppress the punctuation that would be added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Silva2000,
    author = {family=Silva, given=Edmundo de Macedo Soares e, given-i=E {de\nopunct} M S {e\nopunct}},
    title = {Title},
    date = {2000},
}

@book{Silva2010,
    author = {Silva, Ligia Osorio},
    title = {Title 2},
    date = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcites{Silva2000}{Silva2010}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bloody Brazilians! ;) Nice discovery, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given the discussion with @moewe in the comments, I opted for a workaround from the point of view of the original problem, but one which has some desirable side effects (from my perspective, this may well not be what you want). The workaround is to specify directly the name parts in extended format, and to set the abbreviated form, in particular, in a such a way that name particles as "de" (=von) or "e" are not used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Silva2000,
    author = {family=Silva, given=Edmundo de Macedo Soares e, given-i=E M S},
    title = {Title},
    date = {2000},
}

@book{Silva2010,
    author = {Silva, Ligia Osorio},
    title = {Title 2},
    date = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcites{Silva2000}{Silva2010}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Which, in my view, seems a sensible way to abbreviate the name anyway. Especially if you usually go with `useprefix=false` as I do (and as is the default).