# how to cite correctly with Dipl.-Ing prefix and more author names?

Tags: biblatex

I want it only show as

> [1] Dipl.-Ing.(FH)Grunewald, Tobias; Dipl.-Ing. Liers, Henri, Analyse spezieller Unfallszenarien

in footcite, and complete information in bibliography,so as

> [1]Dipl.-Ing.(FH)Grunewald, Tobias; Dipl.-Ing. Liers, Henri, Analyse spezieller Unfallszenarien, Tech.rep. pp. 9, 25, 44, Technische Universität Dresden, October, 2012,

Now the problem is it only shows not correctly in footnote and in both footnote and bibliography there is no "[1]" before the citation info.

How can I change the code in order to show it correctly?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}% Much better than:
% \setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
% \setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=numeric,
        natbib=true, 
        ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}% Generally last package loaded
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
linkcolor={black},
citecolor={blue!50!black},
}
\begin{filecontents}{mycitation.bib}
@TechReport{ASU,
  Title                    = {Analyse spezieller Unfallszenarien},
  Author                   = {{{\relax Dipl.-Ing.(FH)}Grunewald, Tobias; {\relax Dipl.-Ing.} Liers, Henri}},
  Institution              = {Technische Universität Dresden},
  Note                     = {pp. 9, 25, 44},
  Year                     = {October, 2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
% Define new \footcite like command with number and author
\DeclareCiteCommand{\partcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
   \setunit{\addnbspace}
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}}%
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\partcites}{\partcite}{\addsemicolon\space}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{mycitation.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is test 1. \footnote{\label{ASU}\partcite{ASU}}

This is test 2. \footnoteref{ASU}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you go back to your old questions and see if there are some suitable answers for you to accept, before posting more questions?

Comment: Why would you even consider listing the authors' diplomas? After all, nobody ever states "Professor", "Dr.", or "Ph.D." for authors who are university professors and/or hold doctoral degrees. Put differently: What's so special about "Dipl.-Ing.(FH)}"?

Comment: I forgot to accept answer from one of my old posts, but now I have accepted all answers from my previous posts. None of them can completely solve my current problem.  Thank you for your suggestion anyway. @samcarter

Comment: You are right, it´s not common rule, but in Germany it´s more polite if you use them. And I used such prefix in the title page of my thesis, so do the other German students. As you can see, the article itself is in German, that´s how the original author put their names. I just want to keep as they are. Thus I am searching for solution here. @Mico

Comment: @Vivian - How one refers to persons on the title page of one's thesis and whether authors chose to affix titles to their names on the title page of a publication should be matters that are entirely separate from how their names ought to be listed in a bibliography. A main criterion is consistency: *Unless* you use titles such as "Professor" and "Dr." (and "Dr. h.c.", and so on) for *all persons* who are, in fact, professors and/or hold doctoral and other advanced degrees, there should be no reason for providing special treatment for persons whose professional title happens to be "Dipl.-Ing.".

Comment: Apart from the prefix, how is it possible to correct the script?@Mico

Comment: Mhhh it is very uncommon (also in Germany as far as I know) to include titles and degrees in the bibliography. I have certainly never seen this in a scientific/academic publication (thesis, article, book); maybe it happens from time to time in more popular scientific works, but I wouldn't want to go there. On the title page of your thesis you can of course refer to all people involved in all their academic glory with titles and degrees and all. But it is very, very unusual to do so in the bibliography.

Comment: Furthermore, when I ran you example I got a '[1]'  in both the footnote created by `\partcite` as well as the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess there is sth wrong with the setting. I will check it again @moewe

Answer (score 1):

It is very, very unusual to include titles in the bibliography. So no bibliography style I know of has proper support for titles. You could try abusing the 'von' part

```
author = {{Dr.} Elk, Anne},
```

but that will not yield satisfactory results in all (most?) cases.

With `biblatex` you can declare new name parts ([Bibtex/Biber: how to cite an author using Ethiopian conventions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313176/35864)) which you could use to handle titles.