# Changing order of authors based on langid field using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hungarian

I would like to change certain aspects of how the bibliography looks for those entries that are in Hungarian, i.e. marked as `langid = {magyar}` in the bib file. Changing the look of the bibliography based on the langid field works well in these cases for example:

```
% no comma between family and given name if langid is magyar
\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
     test {\iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}}%
  }{}{,\space}%
}
% book title is in italics if langid is magyar
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{
    \ifboolexpr{%
         test {\iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}}}{\emph{#1}}{#1}}
```

[image]

With the code below I can change the order of authors to family name first then given name, which I would like to have for Hungarian names, but this modifies the order of all names not just the Hungarian ones:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

[image]

And so I would like to introduce the same condition as in the above examples that only those names should have the family-given order where `langid={magyar}` in the bib file, but this gives an error:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{
\ifboolexpr{%
     test {\iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}}}{family-given}{given-family}}}
```

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.45 ...id}{magyar}}}{family-given}{given-family}}
                                                  }
?
```

How can I change the order of authors to family-given for the bib entries for the Hungarian language entries?

Full minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{hungarian}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-comp,
    sorting=nyt,
    maxbibnames=10,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{KovacsKiss2022,
  author    = {Kovács, Béla and János Kiss},
  date      = {2022},
  title     = {A {Hungarian} book with two authors},
  location  = {Budapest},
  publisher = {Kiadó},
  langid    = {magyar},
}

@Book{Smith2022,
  author    = {Smith, John and Leslie Taylor},
  date      = {2022},
  title     = {An {English} book with two authors},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address   = {City},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
     test {\iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}}%
  }{}{,\space}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{
    \ifboolexpr{%
         test {\iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}}}{\emph{#1}}{#1}}
         
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{
\ifboolexpr{%
     test {\iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}}}{family-given}{given-family}}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{Smith2022,KovacsKiss2022}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for making a really clear question with a minimal example!

Comment: @Alan Munn yes, thank you, "first" should have been "family", I edited the minimal example to the intended correct code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\DeclareNameAlias` only lets you select an existing name format. It does not allow for complex logic, for that you need `\DeclareNameFormat`.

We build upon the definition of `family-given/given-family`, which can be found in [`biblatex.def` (ll. 910-940)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/868b79fecb7998742eae53d2f81bb637453ceaf7/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L910-L940). Since the format already inverts the first name in the list into family-given order, we we just add a test to also do so if the entry is in Hungarian.

Note that if `\iffieldequalstr` is the only condition you test for, it need not be wrapped in `\ifboolexpr`. `\ifboolexpr` only needs to come in if you want to combine several tests with "or" or "and".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hungarian}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxbibnames=10, maxcitenames=2,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}
    {}
    {\addcomma\space}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}
    {\emph{#1}}
    {#1}}
         
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family:hungarian}

\DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family:hungarian}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}}
    or test {\iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{KovacsKiss2022,
  author    = {Kovács, Béla and János Kiss},
  date      = {2022},
  title     = {A {Hungarian} book with two authors},
  location  = {Budapest},
  publisher = {Kiadó},
  langid    = {magyar},
}

@Book{Smith2022,
  author    = {Smith, John and Leslie Taylor},
  date      = {2022},
  title     = {An {English} book with two authors},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address   = {City},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Smith2022,KovacsKiss2022}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: Hivatkozások Kovács Béla és Kiss János (2022). A Hungarian book with two authors. Budapest: Kiadó. Smith, John és Leslie Taylor (2022). An English book with two authors. City: Publisher.]

Depending on what you want to happen to the other name formats (e.g. "edited by ...") it may be more elegant to define a new bibmacro for Hungarian names and switch to using that on a case-by-case basis.

If you want to support lists of Hungarian and non-Hungarian names a different approach might be needed. `nametemplates` could help here (but might also be overkill): [Bibtex/Biber: how to cite an author using Ethiopian conventions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313176/35864).

Answer (score 3):

There may be a more elegant way to do this (so I would wait a bit before accepting this as an answer), but you can put your conditional inside `\AtEveryBibitem` to select the `sortname` alias that way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{hungarian}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-comp,
    sorting=nyt,
    maxbibnames=10,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{KovacsKiss2022,
  author    = {Kovács, Béla and János Kiss},
  date      = {2022},
  title     = {A {Hungarian} book with two authors},
  location  = {Budapest},
  publisher = {Kiadó},
  langid    = {magyar},
}

@Book{Smith2022,
  author    = {Smith, John and Leslie Taylor},
  date      = {2022},
  title     = {An {English} book with two authors},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address   = {City},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
     test {\iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}}%
  }{}{,\space}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{
    \ifboolexpr{%
         test {\iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}}}{\emph{#1}}{#1}}
         
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}


\AtEveryBibitem{
    \iffieldequalstr{langid}{magyar}
        {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}}
        {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}} 
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{Smith2022,KovacsKiss2022}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]